# Database backup, only update not download the database again. PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I have one database. And daily have backup. The database postgreSQL. Now the backup every day download the whole database. But i like to only update the already backuped file ( only the changes add to the already downloaded database ) not download always the whola database again, again, again. That is possible? If yes how? If not, have any option to do different way?
I use PG-Admin. DBeaver 7.1.3.

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes this is possible, using continues archiving: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html

Comment: This continues archiving works if i use pg_dump.exe?

Comment: I think you need to [take the base backup using `pg_basebackup`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP) not `pg_dump`, and from that point, [`continuous archiving`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html) will be collecting the "updates" to that base backup.

Comment: No, pg_dump can't do this, just follow the manual.